# How secure is the "read-only" feature of a passive NFC tags?

Tags: rfid

I want to write some data in a NFC tag (probably mifare) then put a permanent lock to it, so it can be read-only.

How secure is that ? As in, how am I certain that nobody every will be able to re-write it after ?

Thanks !

Comment: I would put MIFARE in the category memory cards. RFID tags are usually much more constrained.

Comment: Ok, I'll change my title :-)

Comment: I would like to do an informed guess that logically speaking it is easy show that it is read-only afterwards. How well it is protected against perturbation (i.e. active attacks with lasers, Y-beams and such like) is strongly implementation dependent.